# ActionScript 3 parseFloat returns an exponent decimals less than 1

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, exponent, parsefloat

I have a calculator app written in Flex/ActionScript 3 and I am struggling to understand some of parseFloat's behaviors.  Any string containing a decimal value less than 0 with at least 4 places is returns as an exponent.  Why does parseFloat behave this way and can I get the value as a float instead of an exponent?

```
parseFloat("0.004");
//returns 0.004 like I would expect

parseFloat("1.0004");
//returns 1.0004 like I would expect

parseFloat("0.0004");
//returns 4.0E-4 but I want 0.0004
```

Comment: `parseFloat("0.0004")`; traces 0.0004 for me. `var num:Number = parseFloat("0.0004"); trace(num);` Are you putting it in a string or component? Can you show more code?

Comment: 4.0e-4 == 0.0004, what's wrong? You need to properly format the printing of that number, that's all.

Comment: Thanks Vesper, you're right.  I just needed to switch my thinking.  4.0e-4 == 0.0004 so my focus needs to shift to the string formatting instead of the parseFloat result.